# Добавления значений в таблицу? (php+Mysql)

Tags: php, mysql

есть 3 таблицы

---

book:

```
idbook|name|fioavtora| gadizdan| nameizdan| kolstranic| kolillstr| cena

1|Harri Potter| K.L Foron|2001|USAbert| 360|39|4500
```

ну и тд

---

student:

```
idstudent| FIO| kyrs

921701|Gabrus Kirill|2
```

---

kolstud:

```
book_idbook |student_idstudent

1   |   921702
```

---

---

запросом объеденяю 2 таблицы:

```
select name, FIO from book, student, kolstud where kolstud.book_idbook=book.idbook and kolstud.student_idstudent=student.idstudent
```

Теперь к вопросу как в таблице kolstud добавлять не по id а по name и FIO

Comment: Зачем вы так сложно именуете поля?

Comment: вам удобнее `book_idbook` вместо просто `book_id` или вообще `id`?О_о

Comment: Так зачем вы поле называете `idbook`???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так:

```
INSERT INTO `kolstud` VALUES (
  ( SELECT `idbook` FROM `book` WHERE `name` = 'Harri Potter' ),
  ( SELECT `idstudent` FROM `student` WHERE `FIO` = 'Gabrus Kirill' )
);
```

Удаление примерно так:

```
DELETE FROM `kolstud`
WHERE
  `book_idbook` = (
      SELECT `idbook` FROM `book` WHERE `name` = 'Harri Potter'
  ) AND
  `student_idstudent` = (
      SELECT `idstudent` FROM `student` WHERE `FIO` = 'Gabrus Kirill'
  )
```

Comment: спс все получилось

Comment: получилось но я не понимаю как, 
можешь немножко прокомментировать
т.к мне еще по этому же принципу делать удаление

Answer (score 0):

Быть может

```
INSERT INTO `kolstud` VALUES (1, SELECT `idstudent` FROM `student` WHERE FIO=`Gabrus Kirill`);
```

Comment: Ерунда - понятие не измеримое... Конкретнее